# What is mean by single numerical measure of variability in multivariate observations?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix

Suppose there is matrix $X_{nxp}$ representing n p-variate observations.

We know that the variance-covariance matrix $S$ for the given observations $X$ is way of quantifying the variability in $p$ directions in a p-dimensional space.
But i have read in one textbook that determinant of the matrix $S$ gives the single numerical measure of variability.

How to interpret the determinant of the variance-covariance matrix? If have any geometric interpretation, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite intuition is to imagine a multidimensional ellipse (the data plotted in p dimensional space).  If you find the smallest volume that is likely to hold (say) 90% of the data, the volume will be proportional to the determinant.
Note that another measure of 'size' that is pretty popular is the largest eigenvalue of the variance-covariance matrix (that's associated with the first principal component).